# Display Dataset in gridview ( C# windows application)

Tags: c#, gridview, datagridview

I have a `DataSet` in my `.net` client side which I want to display in GridView. I know the syntax but I can not display it. Would you please let me know my mistake?

```
System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView myGrid = new DataGridView();

myGrid.DataSource = xmlResponse.Tables[0];
```

I know that in this step I should bind my `DataSet` as:

```
myGrid.DataBind();
```

but I can not find this attribute in C# ! All I have is `DataBindings` and `DataBindingCompelete`.

Comment: Is this a Console app (suggested by the title) or ASP.NET website (suggested by the tag)?

Comment: Console app can't have a UI beyond text. It's completely text based. You can pop up a message box, but that's about it. I suggest doing this as a WindowsForms or WPF app instead

Comment: @dotNET: it's console application

Comment: @TGH: oh! obviously I didn't know that, thank you for your help.

Comment: How are you trying to display a `DataGridView` in a console app then? You appear to be mixing up a lot of things here; concepts from ASP.NET, Console apps and WinForms all making their way in, somehow!

Comment: `myGrid.DataBind();` is not required setting `DataSource` is enough for `DataGridView`

Comment: Dude I made a mistake, the project is windows application. I edited my question

Comment: in windows application you do not need to bind your data source that's why you are not able to find bind() method. Debug the project and find that , what is in  xmlResponse.Tables[0] ?

Comment: I have a table with some strings as rows and columns which is set in server side, when I debug the project I can see the table in DataSet Visualizer but I want to display this table to my client

Comment: I believe this is a windows application with C# code behind. I've tried and suceeded....Find my answer below & i believe my answer would serve the purpose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does xmlResponse in your code represent dataset?

Please try this code - I used the dataset and it works.

```
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        ds.ReadXml(strFileName); // strFileName is XML File path
        dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
```